# Having trouble running an if statement within a nested loop in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using an xslt to transform my xml in a way that only those items that appear in the `<AffectedItems>` tag of `<Changes>` appear in the `<Items>` tag. I'm new to xslt so please tell what I'm doing wrong here.
Here is the xml:

```
<Product>
  <Items>
      <Item  itemIdentifier="1102607">
      </Item>
      <Item  itemIdentifier="1890456">
      </Item>
  </Items>
  <Changes>
      <Change>
        <AffectedItems>
          <AffectedItem itemIdentifier="1102607">
          </AffectedItem>
        </AffectedItems>
      </Change> 
  </Changes>
</Product>
```

Here is the xslt's relevant portion:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Product">
  <xsl:variable name="var3_current" select="."/>
  <Items>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item">
      <xsl:for-each select="Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem">
        <xsl:if test="floor(@itemIdentifier) = floor(Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/@itemIdentifier)">
          <Item>
            <xsl:attribute name="itemIdentifier">
            <xsl:value-of select="floor(@itemIdentifier)"/>
          </Item>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Items>
  <Changes>
    <Change>
      <AffectedItems>
        <AffectedItem>
        <xsl:attribute name="itemIdentifier">
          <xsl:value-of select="floor(Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem/@itemIdentifier)"/>
        </AffectedItem>
      </AffectedItems>
    </Change>
  </Changes>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It traverses through all the items but places none in the output xml. So the resultant xml has an empty items tag

```
<Items/>
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output in this case? Are you only trying to output `Item` elements whose `itemIdentifier` are listed under `AffectedItems`? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. My expected output would be just the `item` where the `itemIdentifier` matches.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is one of context. You start off by doing an `xsl:for-each` on an `Item` element, which positions you on that `Item` element, but them you do an `xsl:for-each` on `Changes`. This means it is looking for an element names `Changes` as a child of `Item`, but there is none. So, your nested `xsl:for-each` should look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem">
```

However, there is still an issue with the `xsl:if` within this, as you are now positioned on `AffectedItem`, not the `Item` you were positioned on. This means your `xsl:if` is checking the `itemIdentifier` of the current `AffectedItem` against a descendant node, starting at `Changes`, of which there is none again.

To get around this, your `xsl:for-each` should look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="Items/Item">
   <xsl:variable name="Item" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="../../Changes/Change/AffectedItems/AffectedItem">
        <xsl:if test="floor(@itemIdentifier) = floor($Item/@itemIdentifier)">
            <Item>
                <xsl:value-of select="floor(@itemIdentifier)"/>
            </Item>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, this is not really an ideal approach. Two things could benefit you here. First, is the use of the [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy existing elements. Second, is the use of `xsl:key` to look up `AffectedItem` elements.

Essentially, the identity transform copies everything as-is, then you just need to add a template to match `Item` elements for which there is not `AffectedItem` (which is checked by using the key).

Try this much simpler XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:key name="Affected" match="AffectedItem" use="number(@itemIdentifier)" />

    <xsl:template match="Item[not(key('Affected', number(@itemIdentifier)))]" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have removed the use of `floor` in this sample, as I couldn't see why you were flooring a whole number.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped a lot. Now it's traversing both the loops and it checks the if statement as well but it still doesn't pick the matching items. I'm using the first method because it's only my first day with xslt and i'm more comfortable with that. 
And I've replaced $Item with ../../Items/Item because otherwise it said "undeclared variable Item" and I don't know anything about variables here.

Comment: Take a look at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZC to see the first method in action. However, it is worth your time and effort to learn about the identity template, as it is a fundamental design pattern in XSLT. As you can see from my answer, it really reduces the size of XSLT required.

Comment: But what you told copies the AffectedItems to Items, right? But I need all the attributes of Items (which i haven't shown here). AffectedItems does not have the same attributes.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! I had very little time for this and if it wasn't for you I wouldn't have been able to get this done. Thanks a gazillion!